# Solr intermittent run issues - Jetty service stops abruptly, does not start

Tags: solr, jetty, bitnami

I had just installed Bitnami Solr stack on Windows Server 2012. I am facing this issue where it seems that Solr instance does not want to start up. I also noticed the SolrJetty service does not want to start up. Once in a while it will momentarily run then abruptly stop and not start again.

Solr logs only show the following:
"Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized"

Application Event Logs show the following:
"Faulting application name: prunsrv.exe"

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Bitnami Developer here. I was not able to reproduce the issue. Could you provide more in-depth steps to get to it? Did you add any data to the Solr instance or did it fail just after installing?

Comment: @Juan Hi, thanks for replying. Actually there are no extra steps other than installing Bitnami Solr stack. Solr just fails to run. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other stack or application that could be interferring with Solr? Did you try reinstalling the application? Is it a local Windows Server or an AMI that we can launch?

Comment: @Juan I actually have Tomcat, however it was not running during the installation / run of Bitnami stack. Wonder if it could be the cause.

Comment: Hi, I've just installed the latest version of the installers and everything works fine after finishing the installation. Did your installation finish properly? You can check the log file of the installation at "C:\Users\<<yourUser>>\AppData\Local\Temp/2". Note that it's a temporary folder and it's removed when you reboot or power off the machine. Could you also check if you have a service named "solrJetty" in the machine?